# How can I boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, windows, dual-boot, windows-7

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I love it but I have some files on  windows I also need to get to and I can't seem to get onto windows. I tried restarting but no option came up to boot up into windows. Any help would be appreciated cause I need these files!

Comment: Where did you install ubuntu? did you install on win7 partition?

Comment: Yes I did. Is that bad?

Comment: if you've installed on win7 partition then win7 is removed so you can't boot into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only had 1 drive with 1 partition on your computer then you may well have wiped it and put ubuntu in its place I'm afraid.

If this is what's happened you could try some file recovery tools to try and get some of your files back but in all honesty I haven't had much luck with these.

If you have more than 1 drive or partition on your pc then you should be able to see them in the file manager.

Sorry I can't be of more help, it would help to know how you installed Ubuntu (Wubi, Live disc) and if you did it from the live disc did you select "install alongside windows" or "replace windows".